# Correct way to wait for Event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, task

We are waiting in a Function for a Event to occur. But I don't think the Code is correct (it works, but for me it looks wrong!).

At first, this is the Code my colleague wrote:

```
    public string Dispatch(Request data)
    {
        var uri = ...
        string _result = null;
        using (var ws = new WebSocket(uri))
        {
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _result = e.Data;
            };

            ws.Send(request);
            while (_result == null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }

            return _result;
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to realize this? I think I can use AutoResetEvent, but is this better? Is there a way to realize the Code that the Thread can be reused while it is waiting for an answer? (I know how to do it with TaskCompletitionSource, but is this also correct for Sync Functions?)

My Idea was:

```
    public string Dispatch(Request data)
    {
        var uri = ...

        using (var ws = new WebSocket(uri))
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<Guid> tcs;
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(e.Data);
            };

            ws.Send(request);

            return tcs.Task.Result;
        }
    }
```

or

```
    public string Dispatch(Request data)
    {
        var uri = ...
        string _result = null;
        var event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        using (var ws = new WebSocket(uri))
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<Guid> tcs;
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                _result = e.Data;
                event.Set();
            };

            ws.Send(request);

            event.WaitOne();
            return _result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do it with TCS and make it async.

Comment: _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions. You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_

Comment: I've had done this, but the company wich uses the Code does not use Async/Await...

Comment: This does seem to be an on topic question for code review, however if you do post it there make sure to post *all* of the relevant code (no ellipses) otherwise we will close it as off-topic.

Comment: I'd agree that this belongs on Code Review, but from a personal perspective I'd go down the async / await route, if that's not possible, then I would use ManualResetEvent or AutoResetEvent to achieve this as opposed to a while loop with a sleeping thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to realize this?

Just about any form of waiting would be better than the original code, which is waking up every 10 ms just to check a flag. The only thing that would be worse is to not call `Thread.Sleep()` at all. But that'd only just barely be worse.

> I think I can use AutoResetEvent, but is this better?

IMHO, using `TaskCompletionSource` with `await` is best. Doing so would address your next question:

> Is there a way to realize the Code that the Thread can be reused while it is waiting for an answer?

I.e. with `await`, the thread is in fact freed up for other uses. The method calling `await` will return at the `await` statement, allowing that thread to continue execution of other code. Of course, it means the calling method will need to deal with the asynchrony somehow; generally the way it works is that the `async` gets pushed all the way back up to the top of the thread, e.g. in some kind of event-dispatching loop, such as that found in Winforms or WPF.

You are not specific about *why* your company is not using `await`. If the restriction is due to being locked into an earlier version of .NET, you might not be able to use `TaskCompletionSource` either, as it only is available in .NET 4 and later.

Even if you are using .NET 4 (or later) and can use `TaskCompletionSource`, waiting on the task fails to address your concern about freeing the thread for other uses. This may or may not be addressable; the `Task` class does have the `ContinueWith()` method, which allows you to explicitly provide a continuation delegate to be invoked on completion of a `Task`. But if your `Dispatch()` method itself can't be used in an asynchronous context — i.e. it can't return until the operation has completed — then you have no choice but to block execution of that thread until the operation has completed.

(Depending on the context — too little of which has been provided here to be able to provide specific advice — it's possible that you could dispatch other operations *from* the `Dispatch()` method while it's waiting. But that would significantly complicate the design. IMHO it would be better to just upgrade to .NET 4.5/C# 5 and use `await`…that's likely to be less of a long-term maintenance problem than trying to hack in features that are inherently provided by more modern version of the framework and language).

Finally, I'll note that as a general rule, you should avoid `ManualResetEvent` and `AutoResetEvent`, as these are based on unmanaged Windows synchronization objects and are fairly "heavyweight". .NET provides native synchronization mechanisms that are more efficient. At the very least, you can use the `Monitor` class, with the `Wait()` and `Pulse()` methods; equivalent mechanisms can be found using `CountdownEvent` or `SemaphoreSlim`. Each have slightly different semantics, but all can be used to easily implement a simple signal between threads.